# Calculating and modifying trajectory

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, gravity

I am busy working on a programming puzzle which is rather fun. The help I'm looking for is not with the coding as such but the physics behind it so I thought I'd turn to the Physics stack.

The problem is a classic 2D lunar lander problem where you have a craft which is acted on by gravity and which has thrusters with which it can adjust its trajectory. By the time you take control of the craft it can already have a velocity in any direction. When the simulation starts, the geography of the terrain, the coordinates of a landing pad and the coordinates and velocity of the craft is known. The simulation then iterates with a granularity of 1 sec intervals. With each iteration the new coordinates and velocity of the craft is provided and the algorithm then gets to set a bearing and apply a certain amount of thrust. And then the next iteration takes place... and so on.

I've already solved the problem for fairly simple cases (i.e. the starting position of the craft is higher than the landing pad and there are no real obstacles between the craft and the landing pad. By simply controlling the horizontal speed and the vertical speed I can land the craft.

But I'd like to be able to land it, even in complex cases like where the terrain presents an obstacle between the craft and the landing pad which means the craft will have to ascend before starting its controlled descent.

Oh yes, the craft also has limited fuel so you have to use your thrusters sparingly. So the idea I'm playing with is to calculate the desired trajectory which is a parabola with the craft at one point, the highest point of the obstacle at the vertex and the landing pad at the third point. Something like so:
[image: Trajectory]

So with every iteration I calculate the desired trajectory. Obviously the current velocity of the craft might put it on a different trajectory so step one is calculate the thrust vector that would adjust the trajectory to the desired one. The limitations of how much the craft can be rotated and how much thrust can be applied means that you won't be able to put it on the desirable trajectory in one move but then, with the next iteration the new coordinates of the craft is used to calculate a new desired trajectory and again we try to compensate from the existing velocity.

The plan is to continue doing this until the craft is on a desired trajectory and then just let gravity do the rest.

However, we can't just go crashing into the lunar surface either so as we're approaching the landing pad we'll have to slow down the descent for a smooth touch down.

So finally, here is my question:

Is it possible to slow down the craft by applying reverse thrust and still remain on the parabolic trajectory or will any slowing down change the trajectory? I was thinking that, at any point on the trajectory I can apply thrust in the exact opposite direction of that which the craft is moving in. But I'm not sure that will work. How do I slow down my velocity without changing my trajectory?

Comment: Have the rocket outfitted with horizontal and vertical thrusters and allow players to control the thrusters simultaneously? It might make it complicated though. If your rocket can only speed up or slow down, then the change in velocity during its course will change the trajectory.

Comment: Afraid not. I'm the player so to speak. The puzzle has its rules, I have to code an algorithm that will safely land the craft within those rules.

Still, I feel there must be a way to slow down the craft and still keep it on its trajectory. The way I see it, if I slow down the vertical speed only, it will overshoot its trajectory so I have to slow down the horizontal as well. If I slow down the horizontal speed too much it will undershoot, not enough and it will overshoot.

The question is how do I work out by how much should I adjust the horizontal speed if I adjust the vertical speed by n?

Comment: Unless you allow gimballing of the retrothruster, you will always introduce a vertical distortion of the parabola. It looks like a lot of work, good luck with it.

Comment: There's only one thruster and it points directly downwards. The craft can be rotated at any angle to direct the thruster.

All I want to know is, in which direction do I direct thrust if I want to slow down without changing trajectory.

Comment: In that case draw a vector diagram and calculate how much horizontal and vertical force you need to keep the rocket in trajectory, then with that you can find the angle by which the rocket is tilted.

Comment: OK butI already know in which direction the rocket is moving. Do I need to calculate a vector diagram? Should I just point the rocket 180 degrees from the direction in which it is moving, and apply thrust? That's what my intuition tells me but I'd like some confirmation (or refutation).